# Добавление и вывод из базы с шаблоном MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Делаю тестовое задание - одностраничный сайт, где в первом блоке идет вывод информации, а во втором есть возможность ее добавления.

index.php реализована одной строчкой - include контроллер, который создает подключение с базой данных, берет от туда данный и подключает страничку view.php, где отрисовывается сама страница и через цикл выводятся карточки с данными.

Сам класс базы данных сделан с конструктором PDO и двумя методами: выборка из базы, добавление в базу.

Как правильно организовать второй блок, где осуществляется добавление товара? 
Пытался сделать все в единственном контроллере, который отрисовывает страницу, но тогда появляется бесконечный цикл рендеренга view.php. Создать экзмепляр класса бд в файле action.php, чтобы управлять данными из формы там тоже не получается, выдает ошибку, что отправленные значения null, хотя данные из формы читаются.

Может быть ошибка в самом методе добавления?

```
//////////// MODEL /////////

class Database
{

    public $pdo;


    function __construct (){

        $host = '127.0.0.1';
        $db   = 'Hero';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $charset = 'utf8';
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
        $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

       $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    }


    public function getProfiles(){
       return $this->pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `heros`');
    }

    public function addProfile($photo, $name, $role, $date){


        $sql = "INSERT INTO heros (photo, name, role, date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$photo, $name, $role, $currentDate]);

    }

}
```

Все решил! Как обычно забыл указать $this перед дескриптором подключения и название переменной не совпадало с парметром

Comment: Перенесите код в вопрос

Comment: Почему у вас `$pdo` публичный?